# Jenkins plugin development - environment variables

Tags: java, jenkins, environment-variables, hudson, jenkins-plugins

Is there any possibility to get a map of environment variables that are used in Jenkins?
I am trying to develop my own plugin and need to access the variable BUILD_USER_ID, which is provided by the build user vars plugin.

There is a class called EnvVars, which inherits from TreeMap, but it is obviously empty, if you create an object of this.

```
EnvVars env = new EnvVars();
```

Where are these variables stored , so that I can get them and use them in my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you mean build variables injected by [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) into build.

If you are interested in reading static jobs configuration (from system groovy script for instance), use `job.getBuildWrappersList().get(org.jenkinsci.plugins.builduser.BuildUser.class)` to get user configured instance of [BuildUser](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-user-vars-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/builduser/BuildUser.java). In case of Build User Vars Plugin there is not much configuration to read, though.

If you would like to access actual variable values injected into the build process (from a `BuildStep` for instance), call `build.getEnvironment(TaskListener)` to get populated `EnvVars` instance with all variables. Note that these variables are not available outside of build context.

Comment: Hi @Oliver Gondža, I'm working on a Jenkins plugin and I have a need to make an environment variable available to all jobs in Jenkins. Sort of like a Jenkins global environment variable, except I don't want to have to configure one. I capture the value for the env var from the Jenkins global configuration section of my plugin, but then I'm unsure of how to best expose it as a global env var. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Mig82, Please direct such questions to Jenkins Development mailing list.